# LaTeX Beamer package, compiling only produces 32 slides

Tags: latex, beamer

I've been writing a slide presentation using Beamer, and have written 35 slides (or frames) using \begin{frame} some stuff \end{frame}. The problem is, that on compilation, only the first 32 frames are produced. The typesetter does not report any errors or warnings. Ideas for what is going wrong?

Comment: Was there anything special on slide 32? Figure?

Comment: Maybe you copy pasted new frames to end and forgot an \end{document} in there? Other ways of having mismatched environments (which could produce this kind of behavior) should trigger warnings and errors during typesetting.

Comment: Can you produce a minimal example to show this error?

Answer (score 1):

Comment out slide 32 and see what happens. Repeat for 33, 34, etc. until you've found the slide with the mistake. Then carefully look at the code for that page. It might help to comment out part of that page until you find the line of error.